# Why this type of error occurs while using MongoClient?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

This is my Spring MongoDB configuration file.

```
package kenbox.hcm.authentication.dao;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI; 
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
/*
    Spring MongoDB configuration file
*/

@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig{

public @Bean
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("localhost:27017"),"kenbox");
    return mongoTemplate;
    
}
    
}
```

And I am getting an error while using MongoClient which Says "Cannot instantiate the type MongoClient". Why this type of error generally occurs. Please help me resolving this error?

Comment: `"Cannot instantiate the type MongoClient"` - it means just that, you cannot do that using a constructor. Because it is an _interface_. Try using the `MongoClients.create()` to get that object.

Comment: let me try that also.